# NStimeInterval property error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nstimeinterval

My object declared as follows:

my.h

```
@interface My:NSObject{
    NSTimeInterval time;
}
@property (assign) NSTimeInterval time;
@end
```

my.m

```
@implementation My
@synthesize time;
@end
```

somewhere in the code:

```
-(NSTimeInterval)getTimeInterval:(NSString*)timeStr
{
    NSTimeInterval interval;
    //some code
    return interval;
}


-(void) func:(NSString*)timeInterval
{
    My *my = [[My alloc] init];
    my.time = [self getTimeInterval:timeInterval];
}
```

in the line

```
my.time = [self getTimeInterval:timeInterval];
```

i get error: "incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setTime' "

Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Comment: you sure nothing's wrong in the description? I was puzzled by this question (on seeing nothing wrong above), replicated it on XCode in a very simple project and go no errors whatsoever.

Comment: Are you sure `getTimeInterval:` is declared exactly as `-(NSTimeInterval)getTimeInterval:(NSString*)timeStr`, not something like `- (NSTimeInterval *)getTimeInterval:(NSString*)timeStr` (and in the .h file too)?

Comment: Thank you guys, you lead me to the solution. My code is exeactly as i posted, however i did not declare the function in the .h file which is weired. I always saw warning message in this case saying that class may not respond to the function but this is the first time i've got error.

Answer (score 0):

You function "getTimeInterval" takes a string as an argument, and I presume that you're passing in a NSTimeInterval / double into the function, causing the warning. You should change your

```
-(NSTimeInterval)getTimeInterval:(NSString*)timeStr
```

To take a parameter of NSTimerInterval (which is just a fancy way to say double). If you mean to pass in a string representation of a time and get a NSTimeInterval back, you have a bug in your code, and should change timeInterval variable to a string variable containing your time instead.

Answer (score 0):

This seems strange in so many ways.

I'm pretty sure NSTimeInterval is a just a typedef for double, which makes the definition of the property as assign to be wrong. Remove it and see if it  works.